# JavaScript Tabs Dynamic width .animate() only work one time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am new to JavaScript and I am in the curve of learning so I need just a clue for what I did wrong here. I have JavaScript tabs that contain three tables from datatable that each table has different width. My goal in here is to adjust my tabs for each table width by using `.animate()`, it works the first time but and then next time I click to other tab animation will no longer working.

Here's my  original JavaScript tabs code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    
    
    $("#ledger-tabs").animate({width: "90%"});
    $("#calls-tabs").animate({width: "150%"});
    $("#serial-tabs").animate({width: "70%"});

});
```

I am thinking maybe I should do callback function but seems no luck for me, if someone can just point it out for me that would be wonderful.

```
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current', function(){
        $("#ledger-tabs").animate({width: "90%"});
        $("#calls-tabs").animate({width: "150%"});
        $("#serial-tabs").animate({width: "70%"});
    });

    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body{
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background:#D9D9D9;
}
.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 2px;
}

ul.tabs{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li{
    background: #A2A8B6;
    color: #495E92;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
ul.tabs li:hover{
    background:#3e5697;
    color:#fff;
}

ul.tabs li.current{
    background: #ededed;
    color: #29448c;
    border-top: thick solid #29448c;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-content{
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current{
    display: inherit;
}

#ledger_table, #call_history_table, #serial_table{
    text-align:center;'
    display:none;
    margin:2px;
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="ledger-tabs">Ledgers</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="calls-tabs">Calls History</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="serial-tabs">Serials Number</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="ledger-tabs" class="tab-content current">
        <table id="ledger_table"class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Line</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Reference Number</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Amount Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="calls-tabs" class="tab-content">
        <table id="call_history_table"class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Line</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Total Duration</th>
            <th>Rep</th>
            <th>L1</th>
            <th>L2</th>
            <th>L3</th>
            <th>L4</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="serial-tabs" class="tab-content">
        <table id="serial_table" class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Line</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
            <th>NV2 Serial Number</th>
            <th>NV1 Serial Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div><!-- container -->


</body>
```

Really appreciate any comment and opinion from all.

Comment: what you can do is, basically create 3 classes based on the width % and use CSS3 transition property to animate, toggle on every click. OR may be I actually didnt got you issue. ;p

Comment: Hi, what I trying to achieve is to have the tabs have smooth transition every time we clicked on the tabs, the width for each tabs is define by set the width for each tabs, for example ledger-tabs, width: 90%, calls-tabs: 150% and serial-tabs:70%, at this point the code show the right width for each tabs but I am trying to have better smooth transition across the tab

Answer (score 0):

here I leave a link in [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/k07j5zg5/2/), with tabs working. I no sure what you doing with `animate({width: "90%"});` but maybe you want read [this link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/),

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have smooth transitions whenever moves one tab to another and every tabs has different width depending on the table. So for example when I click on ledger tab the width will set to 90% and if I click to call history tab the width will expand to 150% also if I click on serial tab it will then shrink to 70%. With the code that I have now, the transition only working first time and when I move to other tab it will show the table with the right width but without the transition.